# Optimizing My Random Row Fetch

Tags: php, mysql, random, banner

I have been reading about speed issues in relation to getting a random row via MYSQL and PHP, and wondered how my code might be improved for speed.

I have banner information in my database in a table called "banners" and i want to display a random banner in relation to the position on the page, and add +1 to the view_count for that banner. My method works, but for a busy site where this happens on each page load, can this be improved for speed? Thanks

```
/* Get banners for position 1 then choose a random one to display  */
$banners = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,banner_url,destination FROM ".TBL_BANNERS." WHERE position = '1' AND status = '1'");
$banner_count = mysql_num_rows($banners) - 1;
$rand_offset = mt_rand(0,$banner_count);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,title,banner_url,destination FROM ".TBL_BANNERS." LIMIT $rand_offset, 1 "); 

$banner_id = mysql_result($result,0,"id");
$banner_title = mysql_result($result,0,"title");
$banner_url = mysql_result($result,0,"banner_url");
$banner_dest = mysql_result($result,0,"destination");

/* Add view to this banner */
$database->addViewToBanner($banner_id);
```

The last function uses the query:

```
    "UPDATE banners SET view_count = view_count+1 WHERE id = '$banner_id'"
```

I also need to say, that there probably wont be any more than 100 records in the "banners" table at any one time but there will be holes in the ID. The IDs might go up to say 200 but only half of those will still exist.

Comment: Sorry, is there something wrong wrong with `ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1` (there may actually be something wrong with it, I'm not being sarky, I'm actually asking)?

Comment: I read that this way is not truelly random when you have holes in your tables. For example my current ID's returned on the original query are 9,15,and 16.

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes - doing an ORDER BY RAND() is resource intensive, you notice it a lot more on tables with thousands/millions of rows. IMO it's still fine to use on tables that only have a relatively small number of rows. See http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/ for a nice explanation.

Comment: `RAND()` is a calculated column, and thus cannot be indexed. `ORDER BY` is efficient when backed by an index, not so much otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a random number in php and drill it that way into the PK

The SQL would be

```
SELECT id,title,banner_url,destination 
FROM TBL_BANNERS 
WHERE id = $rand_offset
```

If you miss, run it again. This gives a very efficient seek to one row which will be better than using limit/offset processing

Comment: Okay good tip. I used mysql_result to grab the ID from the random row and used that ID in the second query. Thanks

Comment: If you have a random row already (to get the ID), then you don't need a second `SELECT` to get the rest of the data - you could have gotten that when you fetched the ID. The problem is how to get the random row in the first place.

Comment: But the original query is used to make sure I grab the right records and not just every record in the table (WHERE position = '1' AND status = '1'). Also some records are deleted so I cant just pick a random row.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way to do it, as you can read in lots of places around the internet, e.g. [Anton Titov's blog](http://www.titov.net/2005/09/21/do-not-use-order-by-rand-or-how-to-get-random-rows-from-table/) is to do 2 queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS banners FROM quotes
```

Then generate a random number in your programming language (i.e. PHP use [mt_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)). and feed it into this Query:

```
SELECT * FROM banners LIMIT $generated_number, 1
```

NOTE: this isn't good to use if your table only has a small number of rows. Generally I still use ORDER BY RAND() up until I know there are going to be more than 100 rows in the table.

Comment: So multiple queries isnt always a bad thing? Well the full banners table will have no more than about 50 records in it at any one time so maybe I am actually more efficient to use the ORDER BY RAND solution.

Comment: Not always. Often when dealing with IN(), NOT IN(), or RAND() you are better to do a 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the first `SELECT`, use this:

```
$banners_count_result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_banners FROM ".TBL_BANNERS." WHERE position = '1' AND status = '1'");
$banner_count = mysql_result($banners_count_result, 0, "num_banners");
```

Unless you add and remove new banners every couple of seconds, consider caching this result somewhere.

Comment: Surely this would make it less efficient because that query would only return 1 piece of information (row count)? If i use this, I wont have a random ID to use so it would make the second query more complex.

Comment: This query gives you total number of rows. Then you generate a random number in PHP between 1 and the number of rows you now have, and in the second query, you pull the whole row using the `LIMIT` construct as you did before. You were doing two queries anyway, but your first one (select all rows, ask for the count) was horribly inefficient. This one does the same thing, but in a very efficient manner (select the count of the rows, get the single result row).

Comment: I would have thought using PHP to calculate row count would be quicker than using a MYSQL method but I could be wrong. Even if im wrong, it will still make the second query less efficient because I have to use a offset LIMIT instead of just a "WHERE ID = " clause.

Comment: If you let PHP calculate the row count, it's forcing the database to prepare the result set of `n` rows. If MySQL does it, it only produces a one-row resultset. About the ID thing, the point is - where do you get your `ID` from, in order to use the `WHERE ID = ` clause? It's a chicken-and-egg problem. Unless all of your `ID`s are sequential and without holes, i.e. you've never deleted a single row (or manually assigned an ID), then `row# == ID`; but relying on that is extremely fragile. Also, first make the query, then optimise it - and use `EXPLAIN`, don't guess.

Comment: I get the ID from mysql_result($banners,$rand_offset,"id") but i can only use that if my original query has the "id" row.

Comment: No. Look. If you use that method, that means you've already pulled the whole bloody table (okay, all the rows that match your criteria for the random row), which is a) slow as hell, and b) you already have all the data, so you don't need the second query. It's like buying a phone directory to find someone's address, so you can go to their house and ask them for the phone number. It's already there, you have all the data in the ten-pound book you're carrying around. The choice is this: by the method in my post, you make two quick queries. By your method, you make one huge one.